# How to set up multiple targets per project in premake?

Tags: c++, premake

I am trying to set up multiple targets in premake. Currently, I am focusing on Xcode but hopefully the same idea should also apply to MS Visual studio.

In my workspace, I have one library with currently one build target named after the project name (let's call it "MyLibrary"). Then, I have other projects in workspace that consume this library. Currently, I only support Debug configuration for all projects in workspace but I am trying to add two more targets for my library -- Release and Test. So, I want to have the following targets:

- MyLibrary-Debug
- MyLibrary-Release
- MyLibrary-Test

If I can get the library project to output two targets, I can tell my projects to consume the correct target based on configuration:

```lua
project "MyLibrary"
  --- Create multiple targets

project "DemoProject"
   --- stuff
  filter { "configurations:Debug" }
    links { "MyLibrary-Debug" }
  filter { "configurations:Release" }
    links { "MyLibrary-Release" }
```

This is one issue that I am trying to solve. The second one is tests. Currently, I have a separate project for Unit tests. These tests consume the library and run tests to see if the library works. This works well but I cannot generate coverage report for my library. Tests like this would work better for something like E2E tests, not unit tests. So, I basically need to main two project configurations with everything the same, except for minor changes to also include tests and test library:

```lua
project "MyLibrary"
  kind "StaticLib"
  files {
    "engine/src/**.cpp",
    "engine/src/**.h",
  }

  links { ... }
  -- other config in library

project "MyLibrary-Test"
  kind "ConsoleApp"
  files {
    "engine/src/**.cpp",
    "engine/src/**.h",
    "engine/tests/**.h",
    "engine/tests/**.cpp",
  }

  links { "gtest", "gtest_main", "gmock", ... }
  -- other config in library
```

With multiple targets, I can assign a different configuration for the target and do something like this:

```lua
project "MyLibrary"
  kind "StaticLib"
  files {
    "engine/src/**.cpp",
    "engine/src/**.h",
  }

  links { ... }
  
  filter { "configurations:Test" }
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    files {
      "engine/tests/**.cpp",
      "engine/tests/**.h"
    }

    links { "gtest", "gtest_main", "gmock" }

  -- Set different targets somehow, where each target
  -- sets configuration value
```

Is it possible to do this in premake, especially in a way that it is not Xcode specific? For example, the targets create different binaries/libraries if I am using `gmake`.

Comment: I dont immediately see the connection to lua, is it related to the content of `cpp` files your working with?

Comment: Sorry, put the wrong tag. Updated it to c++ since it is about c/c++ projects.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use different `project`s to have different `target`s.

Here's how I understand premake and use it, only with gmake2 so far. It may not be the intended way, but I think it enables to organize the outputs the way you want.

We must have at least one `configuration` at the `workspace` level.

We can have several `project`s in the workspace, each having its own `targetname` for the binary. I then choose what target to build with `make targetname`.

Inside the same `project`, we can use `filter { "configuration:confname" }` to configure a target in several ways (for instance release and debug). It is then built with `make config=confname`. I didn't test for linking but I suppose you can put that under this filter.

So to build a specific target with a specific configuration:

```bash
make config=confname projectname
```

Not specifying the configuration uses the first one, and not specifying the project builds all targets.

I admit the whole method is a little bit clunky in that we have to repeat the configuration filters in each project, even if they are the same everywhere.

Here is a small example.

```lua
-- premake5.lua
workspace "Project Name"

    configurations { "debug", "release" }

    kind        "ConsoleApp"
    objdir      "../build/obj"
    language    "C++"
    cppdialect  "C++20"
    location    "../"
    targetdir   "../bin"
    includedirs { "../include" }

    project "program_name"
        targetname "program_name"
        files { "../src/main.cpp" }

        filter "configurations:debug"
            symbols   "On"
            optimize  "Off"

        filter "configurations:release"
            defines   { "NDEBUG" }
            symbols   "Off"
            optimize  "On"

    project "test"
        targetname "test"
        files { "../src/test/test-program.cpp" }

        filter "configurations:debug"
            symbols   "On"
            optimize  "Off"

        filter "configurations:release"
            defines   { "NDEBUG" }
            symbols   "Off"
            optimize  "On"
```